# Palindrome of a number in Python

Tags: python, palindrome

I am new to python and trying out this code in python compiler and it seems not to work as expected. Based on the logic, this seems to be okay. The output i always see as Not a palindrome. In this case, i expect it to be palindrome.

```py
def func(x):
    temp = x; r=0;
    while (x>0) :
     y = x%10;
     r = r*10+y;
     x = x/10;
     if (r==temp): 
        print ("Palindrome")
     else: 
        print ("Not a palindrome")
    
print (func(121))
```

Comment: You want integer division `//`.

Comment: yes. i want all the data types to be int.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out

```
def func(x):
  temp = str(x)
  if temp == temp[::-1]:
    print ("Palindrome")
  else:
    print ("Not a palindrome")
```